# How to create a class that extends a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Imagine that you have a class in javascript created as it was usual

```
var Button = function( width ){
    this.width;
}
var button = new button(13);
```

And now I want to extend it using nice ES6 classes

```
class ColorButton extends Button {
    constructor( width, color ){
        super(width);
        this.color(color);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Do you specifically only want to do extension with the ES6 syntax? Or do you just want to know how to do object extension in javascript in general?

Comment: Check out this source:
http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/07/introduction-to-es6-classes-tutorial/

Comment: As soon as you declare a `.color()` method somewhere, yes it will "work". Or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. My problem is that `super` method doesn't seem to work at all. See @Andrew code a bit modified http://bit.ly/1bXhYhg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve my problem by myself. To make a javascript class made as a function extendable, it is needed to set the constructor explicitly in the prototype:

```
var Button = function( width ){
    this.width = width;
}

// This is the key part
Button.prototype = {
  constructor: Button
}

class ColorButton extends Button {};
var subButton = new ColorButton(25);

console.log( subButton.width ); // 25, it works!
```

Comment: At least if you use the babel transpiler. It should work with pure ES6.

Comment: I would use `Button.prototype.constructor: Button` instead of setting the whole prototype. The reason is because if you want this solution to be general enough for others to use, you don't want to allow the `Button` function to be free to have any prototype it wants.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to [work as expected in Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=%20%20%20%20var%20Button%20%3D%20function(%20width%20)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.width%20%3D%20width%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.width)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20superButton%20%3D%20new%20Button(13)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ColorButton%20extends%20Button%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(%20width%2C%20color%20)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(width)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.color)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20subButton%20%3D%20new%20ColorButton(25%2C%20%22Red%22)): *(Code has been modified for the example)*

```
var Button = function( width ){
    this.width = width;

    console.log(this.width);
}
var superButton = new Button(13);

class ColorButton extends Button {
    constructor( width, color ){
      super(width);
      this.color = color;

      console.log(this.color);
    }
}
var subButton = new ColorButton(25, "Red");
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, but the `super`call in the constructor seems not to work: http://bit.ly/1bXhYhg

Comment: @marquex: Your super class prototype must have a `.constructor`. Works [if done properly](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=var%20Button=function(w){%0A%09this.w=w%0A%09console.log(this.w)%0A}%0AButton.prototype.sayHi=function(){%0A%09console.log('Hi%20'+this.w)%0A}%0Avar%20superButton=new%20Button(13)%0Aclass%20ColorButton%20extends%20Button{%0A%09constructor(w,c){%0A%09%09super(w)%0A%09%09this.c=c%0A%09%09console.log(this.c)%0A%09}%0A}%0Avar%20subButton=new%20ColorButton(25,%22Red%22)%0AsubButton.sayHi())

Comment: @marquex If you check the Babel REPL link in the answer you will see down the bottom of the screen the `console.log()` call is outputting both 13 and 25, so the super call is working as expected; at least with Babel :)

Comment: @AndrewOdri but the first 13 is printed out by the instantiation in the line 6. It should print the number 13 twice.